# how to move inner div behind surrounding div

Tags: html, css, z-index

My HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Lorem Ipsum
        <div class="innerest">
            <!-- no content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        Lorem Ipsum
        <div class="innerest">
            <!-- no content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.outer {
    background: red;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    background: green;
    z-index: 11;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.innerest {
    background: blue;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 9;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jsnlry/ycJdy/

I want the blue boxes to be behind the red one. It seems, that z-index is ignored in this case. But why?

Any idea?

Comment: allways used z-index with position

Comment: this [link](http://phrogz.net/CSS/zIndex.html) useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/WJzRY/

```
.innerest {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**Why This Works...**

By default, `z-index` is `auto` which computes to 0, all elements have the same stacking level.

In my fiddle, I set up a sequence of styles to show what is happening.

You start off with a parent div with two floated children which are out of flow, and the parent height collapses to 12px high because of the padding (Ex 1).

When you declare `overflow: hidden`, you start a new block formatting context and the floated child elements are retained in the context of the parent, which is why the red background fully covers the child elements (Ex 2).

Finally, you can add absolute positioning to the `.innerest` elements, and this takes them out of the flow and they project out of the `.outer` ancestor element.  Note that the floated elements affect the computed height of the containing block, unlike absolutely positioned elements.  On the right `.innerest` element, you add `z-index: -1` which places this element below all the other elements in the stacking order (computed to 0), so you get the desired effect.

**Reference**

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers

Comment: Great! But why is this? Why must the value be negative?

Comment: I need a few minutes to review your code and to compose a coherent explanation that will be useful to someone other than myself.... check back in a bit!

Comment: Thanks, but I think ahdaniels' answer tells everything. It seems to be because of the position-parameter.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Now I have another element below the outer-div and the innerest-div should also be above this one. I added an orange block to my innerest. The blue boxes should be above the orange one. Would be great if you could tell me _any_ way to achieve this. http://jsfiddle.net/jsnlry/ycJdy/25/

Answer (score 2):

In this example `z-index` only works on the `position:absolute` element. Try putting a negative value like -9 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add z-index: -1 to innerest class. it will be work.

```
 .innerest {
 background: blue;
 width: 30px;
 height: 20px;
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a negative z-index (-1) to your .innerest class.

Answer (score 0):

Now used to this code define your `.outer` **class** `position relative` and **remove** `overflow hidden`

```
    .outer {
            background: red;
            padding: 6px 20px;
            position:relative; //add this line 

        }

.outer:after{
content:"";
clear:both;
overflow:hidden;
display:table;
}

    .innerest {
        z-index: -1; // add this line
        position: absolute;
    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/ycJdy/11/)**